# Runspace issus using async APIs from Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, dotnet-httpclient

I am invoking a library in Powershell that using the .NET HttpClient to make a POST request. The client call runs on a background thread. It works fine for HTTP. When I use HTTPS however I run into issues. The server is not using a valid signed cert. I disabled that check properly using:

`[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}`

only to be met by this error related to runspaces:

> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: There is no
>   Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. You can provide one
>   in the DefaultRunspace property of the
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block
>   you attempted to invoke was: $true

From a bit of research it appears to be related to the fact that the API is async / using tasks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and use a cert policy instead?

```
add-type @" 
    using System.Net; 
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; 

    public class NoSSLCheckPolicy : ICertificatePolicy { 
        public NoSSLCheckPolicy() {} 
        public bool CheckValidationResult( 
            ServicePoint sPoint, X509Certificate cert, 
            WebRequest wRequest, int certProb) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
"@ 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = new-object NoSSLCheckPolicy
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware that when you turn off validation, you're turning it off for everything -- I'd write a validator like a bit more carefully than what @Trondh's recommending -- don't just return true, makes sure the cert is at least valid (even if self-signed), and only allows self-signed certs only for specific domains.

FWIW, I wrote a Tuneable SSL Validator for .Net while working at Splunk to deal with the fact the Splunk uses self-signed certs by default. It has a PowerShell module with commands to let you trust a cert for a session, or just disable certificate chain validation (so you can trust valid self-signed certs with no cert chain) ... and it has wrappers around `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` and even `Export-ODataEndpointProxy` to add an `Insecure` switch so you can disable SSL for just a single request.

https://github.com/Jaykul/Tunable-SSL-Validator