# AWS PowerShell customize SSO Callback: There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net, aws-sso

I'm using the PowerShell (v7) script below to customize AWS SSO Login FLow.  It's based on a working .net implementation:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Import-Module -Name "AWSPowerShell.NetCore"

$profileName = "my-sso-profile"

$chain = New-Object Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfileStoreChain

$credentials = $null
$chain.TryGetAWSCredentials($profileName, [ref]$credentials)

$ssoCredentials = [Amazon.Runtime.SSOAWSCredentials]$credentials
$ssoCredentials.Options.ClientName = "Example-SSO-Script"
$ssoCredentials.Options.SsoVerificationCallback = [System.Action[Amazon.Runtime.SsoVerificationArguments]]{
    param($x)
    # Launch SSO Login Flow in Browser
    Start-Process $x.VerificationUriComplete
}

Set-AWSCredential -Credential $ssoCredentials
# Print details about current Credential
Get-StsCallerIdentity
```

#### Error

When I run this script in Powershell (v7), I get an exception:

> **There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread.**  You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block you attempted to invoke was:   param($x)     …cationUriComplete

Looks like there is an issue invoking my script delegate in`$ssoCredentials.Options.SsoVerificationCallback`

#### Question

How can I configure my Script/PowerShell Session so that my `SsoVerificationCallback` delegate executes without throwing an error?

#### Research

I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the [C# code invoking the SsoVerificationCallback delegate](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/SSOOIDC/Custom/Internal/_bcl45%2Bnetstandard/CoreAmazonSSOOIDC.cs#L138), which is now a PSScriptBlock(?), and something going wrong marshalling back and forth between C# and PowerShell.

Looking around SO, the [`SsoVerificationCallback` invocation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/SSOOIDC/Custom/Internal/_bcl45%2Bnetstandard/CoreAmazonSSOOIDC.cs#L138) isn't Async, though it is invoked inside an async method [`GetSsoTokenAsync`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/SSOOIDC/Custom/Internal/_bcl45%2Bnetstandard/CoreAmazonSSOOIDC.cs#L110), so I don't think [Runspace issus using async APIs from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360980/runspace-issus-using-async-apis-from-powershell) applies.

And I'm not making a web call directly, so tips in blog such as https://www.agilepointnxblog.com/powershell-error-there-is-no-runspace-available-to-run-scripts-in-this-thread/ recommended setting `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $null` also didn't make any impact.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm hazy on the details, the following general information may be helpful:

While PowerShell [*script blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `({ ... }`) generally *can* be used as *.NET delegates*, their *invocation* only succeeds if the calling thread has a PowerShell [runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace) associated with it - script blocks cannot execute otherwise.

If a given script-block-based delegate is called (back) from the PowerShell session's own foreground thread, this requirement is by definition met; e.g., passing a script block as a [`MatchEvaluator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator) delegate to [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace):

```sh
PS> [regex]::Replace('woo', 'o$', { param($m) $m.Value + 't!' })
woot!
```

However, it seems that in your case a *different* thread - one without an associated PowerShell runspace - is calling your script-block-based delegate, which results in the error you saw.

There *may* be a - cumbersome, nontrivial - workaround based on ad-hoc compilation of C# code, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53789011/45375).

Comment: Thank you for this - it was extremely helpful. Thinking now I'll need to add some additional C# code to handle the multi-threading so a PowerShell doesn't need to pass in a delegate across multiple threads.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @PhilipPittle. Good luck, and if you find a solution, I encourage you to post it as an answer here.